# Correct way to continue on after a generator function

Tags: javascript, generator, promise

I have the following generator function:

```
BulkLoader.prototype.load = function(password) {
  var self = this;

  return async(function * () {
    try {
      self.users = yield getJSON('/users');
      self.contacts = yield getJSON('/contacts');
      self.companies = yield getJSON('/companies');

      return self;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
};
```

The `asyc` method looks like this, which I took from the Q library:

```
export default function async(generatorFunc) {
  function continuer(verb, arg) {
    var result;
    try {
      result = generator[verb](arg);
    } catch (err) {
      return RSVP.Promise.reject(err);
    }
    if (result.done) {
      return result.value;
    } else {
      return RSVP.Promise.resolve(result.value).then(callback, errback);
    }
  }

  var generator = generatorFunc();
  var callback = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
  var errback = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");

  return callback();
}
```

My calling code looks like this:

```
var bulkLoader = new GeneratorBulkLoader();

bulkLoader.load()
  .then(render)
  .catch(errorHandler);
```

This seems a bit weird having to work with promises after calling a generator function.

How do other people handle their calling code when working with generators?

Comment: How do you expect to use a generator function then?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:es6-promise] while including code from Q that uses RSVP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems a bit weird having to work with promises after calling a generator function.

Why? The API is still a promise. Whether it did use generators internally does not make a difference.

> How do other people handle their calling code when working with generators?

You can always use generators to sugar your calling code as well:

```
async(function* () {
    var bulkLoader = new GeneratorBulkLoader();

    try {
        yield render(yield bulkLoader.load())
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ironically the calling code with promises was significantly clearer (actually the callee code would also be much clearer and much more performant with a simple return  `Promise.all(...)`)